# Pivot table design without hierarchy in row fields

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have the following Table :

[image: Data]

I Would like to obtain a Pivot Table with rows independent from each other, i.e. Pivot Table should have ID NUMBER as "Values" and all the other fields as "Rows" and should result in something like this:

[image]

[image: Pivot Table with Rows filtered by TRUE values]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: I was not able to get the result you are looking for with a Pivot table. You can get what you want using countif. Not as elegant, but will provide the output table you're looking for.

Comment: @TimNevins thanks for your suggestion, however getting the result in a Pivot Table form is a non renounceable goal. I want for the user to check all the categories-rows (there are many more, what I have uploaded is just an example) and if she wants to see the details, she can just double click the values.

Comment: You'll need to clarify your problem and provide some working code, but you can obtain the table you are looking for in your examples pretty easily with `Power Query` available in Excel 2010 or later.

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean by "*if she wants to see the details, she can just double click the values*"?